# Источники данных для обучения нейросетей

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, информация

Существуют ли какие-либо источники с наборами данных для обучения нейросетей и машинного обучения? Например открытые базы с фотографиями лиц, животных, автомобилей и т.д. Особенно интересуют лица (именно полная фотография лица, а не рандомные фото из соцсетей)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да существуют, вот 3 полезных ссылки:

1) https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets. Здесь можно найти почти все, от фотографий котов до анализа генома человека.

2) https://www.kaggle.com/datasets Тоже много полезных ссылок на датасеты.

3) https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/ Сабреддит где можно почитать обсуждения о датасетах и запросить тот что не смогли найти

Comment: Также добавлю: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html - сотни всяких разных наборов

Comment: Открытые данные Москвы: https://data.mos.ru/opendata